# Microsoft Graph DriveItem Content Stream?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to be able to download a large file using Graph. To do so, I need to "chunk" the file, because it's too large to fit into the memory available. Unfortunately the only call I know reads the entire file into memory immediately. Is there a way to avoid this? What call should I be using?

The call I'm using is:

```
graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Content.Request().GetAsync()
```

I want to use "CopyToAsync" with a buffer size to send this stream to my response stream, but it blows up on a memory exception before I can.  Supposedly there's a "Range" option in the actual REST call, but I haven't figured out how to use it when using the "GraphServiceClient".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the download URL of the file and chunk the download.

Get `DriveItem` and read `downloadUrl, size` from metadata. Use `downloaUrl` and `Range` header to specify range of bytes to be downloaded.

```cs
private async Task DonwloadLargeFile()
{
    long defaultChunkSize = 50 * 1024;

    var driveItem = await client.Drives["driveId"].Items["itemId"].Request().GetAsync();
        
    driveItem.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl", out var downloadUrl);

    var size = (long)driveItem.Size;
    var numberOfChunks = Convert.ToInt32(size / defaultChunkSize);
    var lastChunkSize = Convert.ToInt32(size % defaultChunkSize) - numberOfChunks - 1;
    if (lastChunkSize > 0) 
    { 
        numberOfChunks++; 
    }

    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(@"C:\Download",driveItem.Name)))
    {
        var chunkSize = defaultChunkSize;
        long offset = 0;
        byte[] buffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++)
        {
            if (i == numberOfChunks - 1)
            {
                chunkSize = lastChunkSize;
            }

            var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, (string)downloadUrl);
            req.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(offset, chunkSize + offset);

            var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(req);
            using (var rs = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
                int read;
                do
                {
                    read = rs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }
                }
                while (read > 0);
            }
            offset += chunkSize + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had actually tried this before posting, but I found that security prevented me from success.  I tried using the same token that the API client used, but that didn't seem to work.  Clearly I'm doing something wrong, so I guess I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: The download url should be pre-authenticated, so it's not necessary to use the token. Probably you can use HttpClient.SendAsync(req) instead of  client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(req)

Comment: OK, I don't know what's different between your code and what I tried before, but this works.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by @user2250152 is a good one and got me onto the right track, but the code itself could use some improvement.  Here's what I'm using:

```
private async Task GetLargeFileAsync(GraphServiceClient graphClient, string driveId, string itemId, long defaultChunkSize, HttpResponse response)
{
    var driveItem = await graphClient.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Request().GetAsync();
    driveItem.AdditionalData.TryGetValue("@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl", out var downloadUrl);

    var size = (long)driveItem.Size;
    response.ContentLength = size;

    long offset = 0;
    while (offset < size)
    {
        var chunkSize = Math.Min(size - offset, defaultChunkSize);
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, downloadUrl.ToString());
        req.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(offset, chunkSize + offset - 1);

        var graphClientResponse = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(req);
        using (var rs = await graphClientResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            await rs.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
        }
        offset += defaultChunkSize;
    }
}
```